Will the surface of a charged conductor still be equipotential if a point charge is kept in the vicinity of conductor?
Will all the points on a charged conductor have same net potential if a point charge is placed near it?
What would exactly happen in that scenario?
I think that the charges would separate out because of induction and the potential due to charged conductor would differ at different points on the conductor but the net potential would be the same at each point on conductor.
Please correct me if I am wrong and provide a better explanation of the scenario in that case.
Interesting observations are also welcome.

As long, as there is a difference of potential on the conductor, charges will move to an new equilibrium. So again the potential is constant. But the distribution of the charges will be different,
